# Variables injected or set in a Twig file are undefined after the first position of an entity reference field

Tags: 8, theming

I have a Paragraph setup that has an entity reference field allowing an editor to select multiple nodes to use in a display.

Based on the count of nodes, I want to trigger a class. I figured a way to do this was with `hook_preprocess_node()` in the theme:

```
$referringItem = $node->_referringItem;
    if (!empty($referringItem)) {
      $referringEntity = $referringItem->getEntity();

      if (
        !empty($referringEntity)
        && ($referringEntity instanceof NodeInterface || $referringEntity instanceof Paragraph)
       ) {
        $referringEntityType = $referringEntity->getType();
        $referringEntityTypeId = $referringEntity->getEntityTypeId();
      }
    }

if ($referringEntityType == 'homepage_feature') {
        $count = $referringEntity->get('field_items')->count();

        // Default.
        $variables['top_image'] = FALSE;
        $variables['right_image'] = FALSE;

        // Should this be count is only 1 AND it is the first delta item in field_feature?
        // If not, any single item Homepage Feature will get top-image which may not be
        // desired.
        if ($count == 1) {
          $variables['top_image'] = TRUE;
        }
      }
```

The logic above might be too involved. Basically I am looking back to see what paragraph type was used, so I can pass new variables to the template.

What I noticed is that even though the code is hit for every node listed, the variables only exist in the first node. I dumped them in the template and it is correct there, but they are undefined in the other nodes.

In Twig, I tried dumping the variable at the top of the template:

`{{ top_image }}`

I can see it in the first record `1` above the markup, and then it never shows again.

How can I ensure the variables are passed to the template, correctly, every time?

**Edit**:

Looks like using the same node with the same view mode in different paragraphs or entity references on the same page can cause this to happen.

Is the solution then to add cache tags/context to the node being rendered to account for what parent is outputting it?

Comment: You can't count on the property `_referringItem` being present in preprocess, because this is added by the field formatter for internal use and when the node is rendered you might have a new instance of the node object. A solution might be extending the field formatter, add the information you want to the build array of the field elements and add cache keys (tags/context won't help in this case and you need to add the cache keys in the field formatter, preprocess is too late).

Comment: Where are the keys added? The only place I see it is EntityReferenceFormatterBase::view. So this formatter would be applicable to Paragraphs and change that from Rendered Entity to the new one?

Comment: Where exactly do you want the class being added? Isn't it also that when dumping a variable multiple times with Kint and they all have the same output that Kint sometimes only shows one value? And: Why don't you simply load the paragraph and from there the field and count its items?

Comment: The class is added on the node, but the class (there are others) is entirely dependent upon where it is in the list (multi reference paragraph) or if its just a single entry. So the information has to get communicated somehow. The Paragraph type also allows for multiples. The thought is, using the node and view mode and altering the CSS classes based on that.

Comment: It's not the revision based reference field used to reference paragraphs. To reference nodes you use at the moment `EntityReferenceEntityFormatter`, which is based on the class you've mentioned and inherits view() which sets this property. When you extend this class and assign a new id and label in the annotations you can add the plugin in UI when configuration the view mode of the paragraph.

Comment: OK, then preprocess node, check view mode, load paragraph field, foreach through all paragraphs, check type, if right type, load field, count items, add class. No?

Comment: @leymannx, yes, there could be a solution in preprocess, but the node preprocess is too late. Perhaps it's possible in the parent paragraph preprocess hook, retreiving there the information like you said and add it to the node reference field including the cache keys.

Comment: Wow 4k4, that seemed to do the trick. I'll update the question with what I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments to the question, I extended the `EntityReferenceEntityFormatter` class and modified one part in the `viewElements` method (the rest is the same):

```
  $view_builder = $this->entityTypeManager->getViewBuilder($entity->getEntityTypeId());
  $elements[$delta] = $view_builder->view($entity, $view_mode, $entity->language()->getId());

  try {
    $parent = $items->getParent();
    $parent_entity = $parent->getValue();
    $elements[$delta]['#cache']['keys'][] = $parent_entity->id();
    $elements[$delta]['#cache']['keys'][] = $parent_entity->bundle();
    $elements[$delta]['#cache']['keys'][] = $parent_entity->getEntityTypeId();
    $elements[$delta]['#cache']['keys'][] = 'context_aware';

    // Add special information for different paragraph types.
    if ($parent_entity->getEntityTypeId() == 'paragraph') {
      if ($parent_entity->bundle() == 'homepage_feature') {
        $elements[$delta]['#style_flags']['top_image'] = FALSE;
        $elements[$delta]['#style_flags']['right_image'] = FALSE;

        if ($parent_entity->get('field_items')->count() === 1) {
          $elements[$delta]['#style_flags']['top_image'] = TRUE;
        }
      }
    }
  } catch (\Exception $e) {
    // Add logging
  }
```

Later on, down in preprocess_node:

```
// ONLY for the homepage handling of featured content.
      if ($referringEntityType == 'homepage_feature') {
        $variables['top_image'] = $variables['elements']['#style_flags']['top_image'];
        $variables['right_image'] = $variables['elements']['#style_flags']['right_image'];
      }
```

I was able to then add the same node in the same paragraph type multiple times with the correct information. The correct classes are now applied.

Edit:

Just to add to this too, be sure to set your cacheable dependencies so any change to what holds references will not require a cache clear:

```
$parent = $items->getParent();
$entity->addCacheableDependency($parent);
```

Edit 2:

Thanks to extra guidance from 4k4, I injected the renderer service and reduced down to:

```
    $parent = $items->getParent();
    $parent_entity = $parent->getValue();
    $elements[$delta]['#cache']['keys'][] = $parent_entity->id();
    $elements[$delta]['#cache']['keys'][] = $parent_entity->bundle();
    $elements[$delta]['#cache']['keys'][] = $parent_entity->getEntityTypeId();
    $elements[$delta]['#cache']['keys'][] = 'context_aware';

    if ($this->paragraphDisplaySettings->isApplicable($parent_entity)) {
      $elements[$delta]['#style_flags'] = $this->paragraphDisplaySettings->getSettings($parent_entity);
    }

    $this->renderer->addCacheableDependency($elements[$delta], $parent);
```

`paragraphDisplaySettings` is a custom service object that aids in evaluating different flags to pass through from the original code just to keep it cleaner and leaner. It's working great.

Comment: Adding the tags is a good idea, but I would attach them to the render array `$renderer->addCacheableDependency($elements['delta'], $parent);` Otherwise you get again a dependency on the object instance as discussed before. The risk is lower now because of the added cache keys, but I think the render array is a cleaner solution.

Comment: Where is the `$renderer` object? I don't see that mentioned in `EntityReferenceEntityFormatter` or parent classes.

Comment: `$renderer = \Drupal::service('renderer');` see https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/render-api/cacheability-of-render-arrays

Comment: Ah okay, so I should inject the service to my formatter?

Comment: That works. Thanks again for your help, this was very insightful.